# Axial damper type?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pneumatic

I am trying to find again a small plastic damper that I was looking at last year, but forgot the exact name for that type and now I am unable to find it again. Quite frustrating.

It is pretty much a plastic piston with a small hole at the end, which acts as a linear damper and that is pushed back by a spring. Pretty much like those RC shock absorbers, but far simpler and cheaper.

I need to use it for slowing down a small lid and would be the best solution, but can't find the exact name. [image: something similar to this, but far simpler and cheaper]

Comment: A gas strut, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of [coilovers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilover)? They look very similar to the image you posted.

Coilovers are shock absorbers/dampers with a spring wrapped around the outside. They appear in many vehicle suspensions.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "shock absorber" or "damper". You could prefix your search with "miniature". Try McMaster for a start http://www.mcmaster.com/#hydraulic-dampers/=13n5nu9